# How to convert bytes string with wrong codification to normal string?

Tags: python

I have a string in the format bellow, but it seems that I'm really unable to convert it to a normal string, because i really don't know the format of `string_original`.

```
string_original = b'sab\\u00e3o em p\\u00f3'
```

The answer would be:

```
string = 'sabão em pó'
```

Comment: The `chardet` module is useful for guessing the encoding of unknown text, although I'm not sure you have enough text here for it to be reliable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A String encoded into `bytes` can have

- **Two-Digit Hex Escape** Characters `\x**` or
- **Four-Digit Unicode Escape** Characters `\u****` or
- **Eight-Digit Unicode Escape** Characters `\U********`

**Hex Escape** Characters can be decoded using

```
byte_object.decode('encoding') # encoding = utf-* / ascii / iso-8859-*
```

**Unicode Escape** Characters can be decoded using

```
byte_object.decode('unicode-escape')
```

The code implementation for your question would be:

```
>>> string_original.decode('unicode-escape')
'sabão em pó'
```

Since you are unaware of the encoding, you can perform a *byte-wise check* to see what byte values the data holds and maybe convert the `\u` and `\U` to a corresponding `\x`

```
>>> for byte in "ã".encode('unicode-escape'): # ã --> U+00E3
        print(hex(byte))
    
0x5c        --> \
0x78        --> x
0x65        --> e
0x33        --> 3

>>> for byte in "Æ".encode('unicode-escape'): # Æ --> U+00C6
        print(hex(byte))
    
0x5c        --> \
0x78        --> x
0x63        --> c
0x36        --> 6 (Hope you see the pattern by now)
```

Check out [Python's Unicode Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html) for more info about Unicode Characters with Python

Here is a [Chart of UTF-8 Characters](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/) from `U+0000` to `U+00FF`

Comment: Great.I learned something new, I wasn't aware of `'unicode-escape'` encoding.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary there is also `raw-unicode-escape` which sometimes can be also useful. Sometimes `raw-unicode-escape` together with `unicode-escape` may help to decode more complex string - with more \.  [Python Specific Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings)

Comment: `raw-unicode-escape` interesting, learning more just by this thread :D

Comment: @furas I should definitely read that page. thanks a lot

Comment: @furas One more question, what if the string_original was `'sab\\u00e3o em p\\u00f3'` (without byte notation). Is there any better way to covert instead of search for pattern `\\u++++` and replace with `chr(++++)`? I mean exactly opposite of what `ascii()` built-in function does

Comment: `'sab\\u00e3o em p\\u00f3'.encode('raw-unicode-escape').decode('unicode-escape')`

Comment: Thanks very much. Understood and learned.

Comment: @yyz_vanvlet Happy to help **:D**